# How do I gain reputation for the Bilgewater Cartel?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Is there another way to gain reputation for Bilgewater Cartel besides farming heroic instances with a tabard? Waiting loops for random heroics always take 10-15min to find a group for a dd. Are there any quests with Reputation rewards?

Greets,
Rito

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go. Here is the list of [all quests](http://www.wowhead.com/faction=1133/bilgewater-cartel#comments) that award Bilgewater Cartel reputation. Also, here is a link to [all comments](http://www.wowhead.com/faction=1133/bilgewater-cartel#quests) from players related to Bilgewater Cartel. A few of them suggest ways to increase your reputations.

#### An Example: (*Credit: [Fabriciomind's WoWHead Comment](http://www.wowhead.com/faction=1133#comments:id=1180125)*)

> You gain rep running RFC....
>
> Some research...
>
> - XP/Kill: 3xp
> - Kills/Run: 161
> - XP/Run: 483
> - Time/Run: 360sec*
>
> *This time was achieved with a mage(80). When all mobs are dead I teleport to Orgrimar. >This way I save all the time spent to get out of the instance.
>
> -- Friendly >> Honored --
>
> - XP: 6000
> - Kills: 2000
> - Runs: 12,42
> - Time: 74,52min = 1h14min
>
> -- Honored >> Revered --
>
> - XP: 12000
> - Kills: 4000
> - Runs: 24,84
> - Time: 149min = 2h29min
>
> -- Revered >> Exalted --
>
> - XP: 21000
> - Kills: 7000
> - Runs: 43,47
> - Time: 260min = 4h33min
>
> TOTALS:
>
> - Runs: 81
> - Time: 8h16min

*Above example has been edited since the 4.0.3 patch was release.*

Answer (score 1):

My answer doesn't involve quests, but lowbie vanilla WoW instances also give rep when wearing one of the faction tabards.  This is likely the easiest way to get the rep.

Comment: Rito knows about that already, as evidenced by the question. Zie's looking for alternatives.

Comment: In his question he states heroic instances, not lowbie instances.